# Symfony 5, Access accpeted with only a new role doesn't work in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, annotations

In my database, I create a new role called 'D', many users have this role.

I want in my page /designer, only those have the role 'ROLE_D' may access to this page.

In my controller I wrote that

```
/**
 * @Route("/designer", name="designer", methods={"GET"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_D")
 */
```

But it doesn't work

I also tried

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_D')
```

but nothing works

Is it possible to secure with a role other than 'ROLE_ADMIN' and 'ROLE_USER' in a controller?

Comment: I wrote that: `@IsGranted("ROLE_STUDENT")` sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't works.....  you know why?

Comment: did you define the role in `security.yml`?

Comment: The web profiler-toolbar contains a tab for Security. That could help identifying issues in your configuration. You can define your own rules and it should work, but removing the default role (`ROLE_USER`) might cause issues with existing security checks. So instead of only having `ROLE_D` you should add it to the user's roles and keep `ROLE_USER` and just not check for it.

Comment: Thanks dbrumann! I had to delete the `ROLE_USER` on the entity User